# HAL + DMA + UART = STM32 crash

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart, dma, stm32f3

I'm currently working on a project which involves communication between a STM32F303RE (Nucleo board) and a classic GSM/GPS SIM808 module plus other peripherals.

I want to use the DMA + UART of the STM32F303 to receive the data from the SIM808 module so the CPU is free to do something else during the communication. I had a previous working code for this for a STM32F031 (Nucleo also) but because this is not the same architecture, I decided to start from scratch.

The problem is that after the `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA` call, when the amount of received bytes exceed the buffer size, the whole STM32 crashes (sucked in a infinite loop because of a *HardFault*). I've defined the DMA buffer as circular. None of my interrupts (`HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback`) or handlers (`DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler`,`USART2_IRQHandler`) are called. Tried with both UART1 and UART2.

I'm using CubeMX for the code initialisation and SW4STM32 for coding / compling / debugging / etc.

The speed of the UART config is correct, if I use the blocking function `HAL_UART_Receive` I can get the values sent by the SIM808 module.

I tried to debug, but I don't know where does the problem come from. Do you know why the UART & DMA are not working properly and why the STM32 crashes?

Here is my code if it can help:

**main.c**

```
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart2_rx;

#define rxBuffSize 10
uint8_t rxData[rxBuffSize];

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback (UART_HandleTypeDef * huart) {
    if (huart-> Instance == USART1) {
        __HAL_UART_FLUSH_DRREGISTER (& huart1); // Clear the buffer to prevent overrun
    } else {
        __HAL_UART_FLUSH_DRREGISTER (& huart2);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_DMA_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    MX_USART2_UART_Init();

    __HAL_UART_FLUSH_DRREGISTER (&huart2); // Clear the buffer to prevent overrun
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, rxData, rxBuffSize);

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin);
        HAL_Delay(150);

    }
}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PREDIV = RCC_PREDIV_DIV1;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1|RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART2;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK2;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart2ClockSelection = RCC_USART2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* USART1 init function */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

    huart1.Instance = USART1;
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 19200;
    huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

/* USART2 init function */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

    huart2.Instance = USART2;
    huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
    huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

/** 
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel6_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel6_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel6_IRQn);
}
```

**stm32f3xx_hal_msp.c**

```
extern DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart2_rx;

extern void Error_Handler(void);

/**
  * Initializes the Global MSP.
  */
void HAL_MspInit(void)
{

  __HAL_RCC_SYSCFG_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_0);

  /* System interrupt init*/
  /* MemoryManagement_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(MemoryManagement_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* BusFault_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(BusFault_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* UsageFault_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(UsageFault_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* SVCall_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SVCall_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* DebugMonitor_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DebugMonitor_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* PendSV_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(PendSV_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);

}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(huart->Instance==USART1)
  {
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**USART1 GPIO Configuration    
    PB6     ------> USART1_TX
    PB7     ------> USART1_RX 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  }
  else if(huart->Instance==USART2)
  {
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**USART2 GPIO Configuration    
    PA2     ------> USART2_TX
    PA3     ------> USART2_RX 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USART_DEBUG_TX_Pin|USART_DEBUG_RX_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Peripheral DMA init*/

    hdma_usart2_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel6;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart2_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(huart,hdmarx,hdma_usart2_rx);

    /* Peripheral interrupt init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART2_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
  }

}

void HAL_UART_MspDeInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{

  if(huart->Instance==USART1)
  {
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_DISABLE();

    /**USART1 GPIO Configuration    
    PB6     ------> USART1_TX
    PB7     ------> USART1_RX 
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7);

  }
  else if(huart->Instance==USART2)
  {

    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_DISABLE();

    /**USART2 GPIO Configuration    
    PA2     ------> USART2_TX
    PA3     ------> USART2_RX 
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, USART_DEBUG_TX_Pin|USART_DEBUG_RX_Pin);

    /* Peripheral DMA DeInit*/
    HAL_DMA_DeInit(huart->hdmarx);

    /* Peripheral interrupt DeInit*/
    HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);

  }
}
```

**stm32f3xx_it.c**

```
/* External variables --------------------------------------------------------*/
extern DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart2_rx;
extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/******************************************************************************/
/*            Cortex-M4 Processor Interruption and Exception Handlers         */ 
/******************************************************************************/

/**
* @brief This function handles System service call via SWI instruction.
*/
void SVC_Handler(void)
{
}

/**
* @brief This function handles Pendable request for system service.
*/
void PendSV_Handler(void)
{
}

/**
* @brief This function handles System tick timer.
*/
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  HAL_IncTick();
  HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();
}

/******************************************************************************/
/* STM32F3xx Peripheral Interrupt Handlers                                    */
/* Add here the Interrupt Handlers for the used peripherals.                  */
/* For the available peripheral interrupt handler names,                      */
/* please refer to the startup file (startup_stm32f3xx.s).                    */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
* @brief This function handles DMA1 channel6 global interrupt.
*/
void DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_usart2_rx);
}

/**
* @brief This function handles USART2 global interrupt / USART2 wake-up interrupt through EXTI line 26.
*/
void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);
}
```

**stm32f3xx_it.h**

```
#ifndef __STM32F3xx_IT_H
#define __STM32F3xx_IT_H

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported types ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported constants --------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported macro ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported functions ------------------------------------------------------- */

void SVC_Handler(void);
void PendSV_Handler(void);
void SysTick_Handler(void);
void DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler(void);
void USART2_IRQHandler(void);

#endif /* __STM32F3xx_IT_H */
```

I've been stuck several days on this problem... and could figured out any solution

Comment: Please ask a question, this is a Q&A site

Comment: I don't understand where does the STM32 problem come from, and I'm asking if someone is able to tell me why the DMA / UART is not working?

Comment: Please edit you question and include the question. Thanks

Comment: Check your BufferSize, try to modify it to another values. Try it with 128,256,1024 etc. Usually I use 1024.

Comment: I tried with these values, but same problem: the interrupts and handlers are never triggered, and the STM32 crashes when the received data count reach the buffer size :(

Comment: Did you initalized channel for it? hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_4;
(Just example) Its not the same as instance

Comment: The problem came from the startup file, see my answer. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the problem :)

The startup script file (*startup_stm32.s*) was not good, the declaration of each handler and interrupt was missing. Added it and now the DMA + UART triggers the `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` as expected.

For example:

```
.weak   DMA1_Channelx_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA1_Channelx_IRQHandler,Default_Handler
```